# Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager can not track online user continuity in the web game

Tags: angular, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

Hi I am a beginner of GA and GTM. 
I have a web game without router written by Angular 2+ and I intend to track user behavior while they play my game.

At the beginning, I integrated tracking code into my app and worked fine. 
GA can track who is online. But after a period of time it shows 0 user online. During this time, I played my game continuously.

How do I resolve this problem?
By the way, any interactive actions are websocket not HTTP request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A session expires after 30 minutes of inactivity (adjustable to up the four hours in the property settings), so if you send an inital pageview and then no more interactions your user sessions will expire even though they are still on the page (since GA measures activity by the tracking calls send to the GA server).

In the function that trigger the interactions with the game you would need to include a call to the Google server to update the user session (presumably some event with achievements in the game for the user, so you can build reports on how your users progress through the game).

Comment: I observe for some time, GA will loss tracking online user about 5 to 10 minutes. I added a script to send HTTP request per minutes but it didn't work. This issue still happen.